# addEventListener on proxied Event Target

Tags: javascript, proxy, javascript-objects, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create an object that is basically both a `Proxy` and an `EventTarget`. The goal is to be able to subscribe to any changes made to this object.

Here's how I define this object:

```js
const target = new EventTarget()
const state = new Proxy(target, { 
    set: (obj, key, value) => { 
        Reflect.set(obj, key, value)
        obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {key, value}}))
    }, 
    deleteProperty: (obj, key) => { 
        Reflect.deleteProperty(obj, key) 
        obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change', {detail: {key, value: undefined}})) 
    } 
})
```

At this point I'd like to be able to call `state.addEventListener('change', console.log)` but this gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

So here's what works:

```js
target.addEventListener('change', console.log)
state.foo = 'bar'
// logs the event
```

But as I said, I'd like to have one single unified object that can be both the target (can be listened to with `addEventListener`) and the store of values (proxied object in charge of dispatching the events when modified). So far, this method only works if you carry around **both** `target` and `state`...

Any idea why I can't call `addEventListener` by going through the `Proxy`?

---

Technically, calling `state.addEventListener()` goes through the `get` prototype method, so I tried defining `get: Reflect.get` in the proxy handler but it adds nothing... (Even though it was indeed reached because I tried adding a `console.log` there too)

So why can't I call `addEventListener` through the proxy but it works fine directly on the `target` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Oh, nevermind... I found the answer... Still posting it though, as it wasn't as straightforward for me as I would have hoped and it might help someone.*

---

The issue is that when the proxy returns a function, the function doesn't have the proper scope (`this`). So you need to bind the proper scope to the returned function.

This can be done by defining a getter:

```js
    get: function (obj, key) {
        const result = Reflect.get(obj, key)
        if(typeof result === 'function')
            return result.bind(obj)
        return result
    }
```

Once this is done, it's as simple as this:

```js
const state = new Proxy(new EventTarget(), handler)
state.addEventListener('change', console.log)
state.foo = 'bar'
// logs the event
```

---

On a *W3C recommendations* level, I am unsure as to why a `Proxy`shouldn't return functions with their proper scope...

Comment: _"I am unsure as to why a Proxy shouldn't return functions with their proper scope"_ how would it know what the proper scope was? It could blindly bind `obj` but then it wouldnt be much of a proxy as it would be modifying parts of the target on its own without your direction. If for instance you wanted to rebind to some other object you wouldnt be able to as it is already bound

Comment: Fair enough. I had never tried double binding a function but I just did and only the first bound scope sticks. The second call to `bind` just does nothing. Interesting...

Comment: Note that the "set" method should "return true" according to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill/issues/20#issuecomment-240027418 and then it all works.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using a proxy you do need to use the getter like you thought but you more than likely didnt bind the function so it would be invoked with the correct `this`. As you lose that connection when you return the function without it, it would instead refer to the proxy object which isnt itself implementing the EventTarget/EventListener methods.

```js
let target = document.documentElement;
let targetProxy = new Proxy(target,{
  get:(obj,key)=>{
    let value = Reflect.get(obj,key);
    if(typeof(value) == "function"){
      return value.bind(obj);
    }
    return value;
  }
});
targetProxy.addEventListener('click',()=>console.log('clicked'));
```

Comment: Sorry for answering my own question before you got a chance to! But going further: is there a reason why proxies don't pass along the functions *with* their scope? Is this just a result of implementation or was there a well thought out reason in the specs?

Comment: No problem self answering is quite alright. As for the question see the comment i left on your answer. Its just an opinion as i dont know the true answer but that seems the most logical reason to me